# Django dependencies reference nonexistent parent node when making model changes

Tags: python, django, sqlite, migration, django-migrations

I have a Django project deployed on aws server.I made some changes in the models on my machine and pushed the changed by Github and on the server, I pulled the changes by git command but the app isn't working so when I tried running `python manage.py makemigrations` it returns errors

> like Django: dependencies reference nonexistent parent node

I tried removing the file mentioned in the error and tried removing the `.pyc` files but still the same problem so what can I do here and how should I do this in the future to avoid these problems.

here's the traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/ubuntu/Eyelizer/eyenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/ubuntu/Eyelizer/eyenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/ubuntu/Eyelizer/eyenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/ubuntu/Eyelizer/eyenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 353, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/ubuntu/Eyelizer/eyenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/Eyelizer/eyenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 89, in handle
    loader = MigrationLoader(None, ignore_no_migrations=True)
  File "/home/ubuntu/Eyelizer/eyenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/home/ubuntu/Eyelizer/eyenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 273, in build_graph
    raise exc
  File "/home/ubuntu/Eyelizer/eyenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 247, in build_graph
    self.graph.validate_consistency()
  File "/home/ubuntu/Eyelizer/eyenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 243, in validate_consistency
    [n.raise_error() for n in self.node_map.values() if isinstance(n, DummyNode)]
  File "/home/ubuntu/Eyelizer/eyenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 243, in <listcomp>
    [n.raise_error() for n in self.node_map.values() if isinstance(n, DummyNode)]
  File "/home/ubuntu/Eyelizer/eyenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 96, in raise_error
    raise NodeNotFoundError(self.error_message, self.key, origin=self.origin)
django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration patients.0007_uploadedimages_processed_image dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('patients', '0006_auto_20190803_2241')
```

update: not the whole app not working but the view of the new/changed model returning a 500 internal server error.

Comment: It looks like you have forgotten to add, commit and push an older migration file: 0006_auto_20190803_2241

Comment: I found that from 0001 to 0006 is missing how do you suggest adding those? and should I add all of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to copy each dependency and paste it's content manually. from 0001 to 0006.